# The default value of an optional parameter must be constant. flutter

Tags: flutter

as you can see below, I want to put a variable UserIDData instead of 1, but it shows me this error, how can I replace it with 1 variable?

**Error:
The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.**

[THIS IS IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oK6yF.png)

Comment: please provide more information (such as code and your purpose by doing this)

Comment: Are you using the deprecated colons for default value instead of the modern "="?  Might not make a difference, but it's good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error when passing the color as argument : I solved it this way

> {Color color = Colors.blue}